# PollingDuplexHttpBinding in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, push-notification

I understand that polling will inevitably have delays in getting real time updates. Currently I am using websync from frozen mountain dot com for achieving this and it works very well. But I would like to still know if PollingDuplexHttpBinding is a worthwhile one.

- Has some one used this in critical systems?
- Is its performance better over comet? When I say performance, how many simultaneous client connections it can handle?
- Is it possible to configure the time interval of polling? I mean once in 30 seconds, 60 seconds etc.,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We're currently using this for our [Alanta](http://alanta.com) web conferencing platform.  Our default binding is Net.TCP, because it's faster and more performant.  But not everyone lets Net.TCP through on the right ports, so if we can't connect over Net.TCP, we fallback to the PollingDuplexHttpBinding.  And it seems to work reasonably well -- no major complaints so far at least.

With respect to performance, the PollingDuplex binding is roughly similar to what you'll find in other long-poll based systems.  You can find more details on its performance on [Tomek's blog](http://tomasz.janczuk.org/2010/03/comparison-of-http-polling-duplex-and.html).

And yes, it's possible to configure almost every aspect of the binding.  The particular properties that control the polling interval are ClientPollTimeout and ServerPollTimeout.  See [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlightws/archive/2010/07/16/pollingduplex-multiple-mode-timeouts-demystified.aspx) for more details.